# issue with web browser control not waiting till events performed?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, web-scraping, web-crawler

Im trying to get into some webpages and get some information, using web browser so that it remembers my login details. things worked till here but for multiple urls web browser document load is not working properly as i want.

My intention was go to url->wait till it loads--> get required data into text--> new url and same process.

i used for loop to change url but when i run all the url's passed one by one not waiting till document loads and writes to text. please help me.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String text = File.ReadAllText("links.txt");

        var result = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");
        foreach (string s in result)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1) + "/" + Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items.Count);
            textBox1.Text += listBox1.Items[i];

            String url = textBox1.Text;
            webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser2.Navigate(url);

     }
   }

    void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceCode = webBrowser2.DocumentText;
        try
        {
           /*someregax expressions to filter text */

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("inks_info.txt", true);
            sw.Write("url" + "~" + sourceCode + "\n");
            sw.Close();

            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        catch
        {

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("inks_fail.txt", true);
            sw.Write(textBox1.Text + "\n");
            sw.Close();

            textBox1.Text = "";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an event handler on the document load for each item, but you're not waiting for it to fire after the first navigation before you initiate the second navigation. Your for loop needs to be "more asynchronous". For example, placing items in a queue and requesting one at a time:

```
Queue<string> _items;
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    String text = File.ReadAllText("links.txt");
    _items = new Queue<string>(Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n"));
    webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted;
    RequestItem();
}
private void RequestItem()
{
    if (_items.Any())
    {
        var url = _items.Dequeue(); // preprocess as required
        webBrowser2.Navigate(url);
    }
}
void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle result
    RequestItem(); // Then request next item
}
```

Your code also looks like it's using UI elements (like a list box) as intermediate variables just for a logical purpose rather than display. You should separate out the logic (using regular variables, data structures such as lists and requesting data) from the display (showing the results in list boxes, updating text boxes, etc). It's not clear that you want to be using a `WebBrowser` even - it looks like you're just downloading text and should use `WebClient` or `HttpClient`. The code can then also be much cleaner using async/await:

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
     string text = await new WebClient().DownloadStringAsync(url);
     // Handle text
}
```

Comment: im using web browser control because the site im trying need to login before i get data so in one web browser im doing login part and from other im trying to get information. im new to this so help if anyother way to make login once and navigate all pages in a site.

Comment: In that case you may be able to do something else with more work (eg manually sending cookies or whatever is used), but I'd try to get this working first.

Comment: Hey your code has really helped me and i could figure out way to get my work done. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple answer. The WebBorwser control sucks for this stuff but here is what you are looking for:

```
WHILE(webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Ready)
{
     Application.DoEvents()
}
```

Thats it.. It will not freeze your app or get you lost in code, it just waits till its don't navigating. You be most welcome.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, there is a fundamental mistake in requesting all documents in one browser before the first document fires a completed event.